# /ɪə/ diphthong in modern speech

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

I'm working on my pronunciation with a teacher from England. So, learning the British accent.
In the last lesson we were discussing `/ɪə/` diphthong. She says that nowadays it should be pronounced as `/i:ə/` rather than `/ɪə/`. I did some research and couldn't really find anything that confirms it. But, I [found](https://pronunciationstudio.com/received-pronunciation-general-british/) that in fact `/ɪə/` shifted towards `/ɪː/`. Similarly to `/eə/` → `/ɛː/`. Also, [this](https://www.englishspeechservices.com/blog/the-demise-of-%C9%AA%C9%99-as-in-near/) seems to support it.
Is my teacher being wrong? What option should I use to not sound old-fashioned? Is it common to use /ɪː/ instead of /ɪə/?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 1930s pronunciation of 'beer' given in your second link definitely sounds old-fashioned.

Comment: @KateBunting Indeed, it's not far from accents lampooned by Graham Chapman in Monty Python...